# PHP Calculate 24 Hours time difference

Tags: php, date, time

I want to check if there are more than 24 hours since the last query made by a function in PHP. First i have to select the last query date and time from the database then i need to calculate it with the current time and check if there are more than 24 hours since the last query. How can i do this exactly? Noob answers needed!

Answer (score 0):

If you have datetime row you can just check number of rows returned like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
if(mysqli_num_rows($link, $result) > 0) {
  // yes there was query in last 24 hours
} else {
  // no there wasn't query in last 24 hours
}
```

Comment: Hm, its not working. My query always recieves query > 0.